# For entrando em loop

Tags: php, for

Estou pegando os valores do array e tentando passar no for, mas ele acabando entrando em *loop* e trazendo os valores 1,2,3,4,5,6....

```
array_push($var, $linha['data']);
array_push($var, $linha['data_th']);
array_push($var, $linha['data_fl']);       

$var = array_unique($var); 

for($i = 0; $i <= $var; $i++){
    echo  "<td><div class='data'>'$i'</div></td>"; 
}
```

O resultado do `print_r` do `$var` é:

```
Array ( [0] => 30/04 [1] => 03/05 [2] => [3] => 01/05 [6] => 02/05 [10] => 07/05 [12] => 04/05 [16] => 09/05 [17] => 18/05 [18] => 05/05 [27] => 10/05 [28] => 14/05 [30] => 11/05 [31] => 15/05 [34] => 16/05 [40] => 17/05 [49] => 21/05 [53] => 04/06 [55] => 22/05 [65] => 26/05 [67] => 24/05 [73] => 28/05 [75] => 25/05 [77] => 18/06 [81] => 29/05 [84] => 30/05 [87] => 31/05 [91] => 05/06 [94] => 06/06 [96] => 01/06 [101] => 15/06 [103] => 08/06 [104] => 29/06 [108] => 07/06 [109] => 12/06 [112] => 11/06 [118] => 14/06 [119] => 28/06 [128] => 00/00 [133] => 22/06 [135] => 13/06 [142] => 19/06 [145] => 20/06 [164] => 06/07 [172] => 25/06 [174] => 21/06 [181] => 26/06 [190] => 27/06 [199] => 02/07 [217] => 04/07 [218] => 15/07 [259] => 09/07 [262] => 10/07 [267] => 05/07 [271] => 08/07 [291] => 11/07 [294] => 12/07 [300] => 13/07 )
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 398  Notice:
>   Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 398  Notice:
>   Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 398  Notice:
>   Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 398 ...

Comment: Não seria `$i <= count($var)`

Comment: Precisamos saber a estrutura dos arrays `$linha` para poder imprimir no loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Erro

Você está tendo `1,2,3,4,5...` porque está imprimindo `$i` (índice) e não o `$var` (valor).

---

#### Corrigindo

```
# junta todos arrays em um array único ($var)
array_push($var, $linha['data']);
array_push($var, $linha['data_th']);
array_push($var, $linha['data_fl']);       

# elimina duplicados
$var = array_unique($var);

# conta quantos registros tem no total
$regs = count($var);

# faz o loop
for($i = 0; $i <= $regs; $i++){
   echo  "<td><div class='data'>" . $var[$i] . "</div></td>"; 
}
```

---

## edit1

```
.....
# elimina duplicados
$var = array_unique($var);

# faz o loop
foreach ($var as $v) {
  echo  "<td><div class='data'>" . $v . "</div></td>";
}
```

---

## edit2

Conforme disse, iria verificar o motivo do erro.

Sempre o último valor do array, iria dar erro, pois como o contador do array (`count`) não considera o `0` como valor, então ele sempre estaria com 1 valor a mais no final.

Para corrigir, é somente tirar o `=` na comparação.

Um exemplo funcionando:

```
$var = Array ( 0 => '30/04', 1 => '03/05', 2 => '01/05');
              
# elimina duplicados
$var = array_unique($var);

# conta quantos registros tem no total
$regs = count($var);

# faz o loop
for($i = 0; $i < $regs; $i++){
   echo  "<td><div class='data'>" . $var[$i] . "</div></td>"; 
}
```

Comment: Ele retorna o array Array ( [0] => 30/04 [1] => 03/05 [2] => [3] => 01/05 [6] => 02/05 [10] => 07/05 [12] => 04/05 [16] => 09/05 [17] => 18/05 [18] => 05/05 [27] => 10/05 [28] => 14/05 [30] => 11/05 [31] => 15/05 [34] => 16/05 [40] => 17/05 [49] => 21/05 [53] => 04/06 [55] => 22/05 [65] => 26/05 [67] => 24/05 [73] => 28/05 [75] => 25/05 [77] => 18/06 [81] => 29/05 [84] => 30/05 [87] => 31/05 [91] => 05/06 [94] => 06/06 [96] => 01/06 [101] => 15/06 [103] => 08/06 [104] => 29/06 [108] => 07/06 [109] => 12/06 ...

Comment: Dá um `print_r($var)` depois de `$var = array_unique($var);` ... Vá em "editar" e poste na resposta o resultado na pergunta.

Comment: Era para editar a pergunta, não o comentário, mas tudo bem! rs... Cara, do jeito que fiz era para ter impresso. Cole o erro novamente

Comment: Dscp, editei a pergunta com o erro.

Comment: Teste com o 2o exemplo

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado parceiro pela a grande ajuda e atenção, Grato.

Comment: Vou ver melhor depois o porque não funcionou seu `for`, pois está correto, deveria funcionar também. Mas geralmente, sempre que trabalhamos com arrays, geralmente se usa o `foreach`. ✌️

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo editei pra acertar, está errado isso? Por isso o -1?

Comment: foi mal, desculpa ai, juro que vi outra coisa na edição.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Opa, tranquilo Leo! Eu achei estranho até perguntei no chat! rs ✌️

Answer (score 2):

[count](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php) - Conta os elementos de um array

```
    array_push($var, $linha['data']);
    array_push($var, $linha['data_th']);
    array_push($var, $linha['data_fl']);       

    $var = array_unique($var); 

    for($i = 0; $i <= count($var); $i++){
       echo  "<td><div class='data'>'$i'</div></td>"; 
    }
```

[**exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/sdEE4L)

**Se queres as chaves/valores**

```
$var = array("laranja", "morango");

    array_push($var, "banana");
    array_push($var, "uva");
    array_push($var,"cereja");       

    $var = array_unique($var);

foreach( $var as $key => $value ) {
   //se quiser retornar só os valores, elimine $key  
   echo $key . " " . $value."\n";
}
```

[**exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/JeaQz4)

Comment: Ele retorna '0'
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
'5'
'6'
'7'
'8'
'9'
'10'
'11'
'12'
'13'
'14'
'15'
'16'
'17'
'18'
'19'
'20'
'21'
'22'
'23'
'24'
'25'
'26'
'27'
'28'
'29'
'30'
'31'
'32'
'33'
'34'
'35'
'36'
'37'
'38'
'39'
'40'
'41'
'42'
'43'
'44'
'45'
'46'
'47'
'48'
'49'
'50'
'51'
'52'
'53'
'54'
'55'
'56'
'57'
'58'
...

Comment: @Aprendizzz você viu um exemplo que coloquei em result no ideone?

Comment: Sim ele retorna o indice e não o valor

Comment: Pois é, sua pergunta original estava mal formulada, induzindo a erro de interpretação, vez que no output você colocou $i, dando margem que queria imprimir os indices